# Delete a table and its content from html code in php

Tags: php, html

I have a html code like below. I want to remove entire table and its content from it using php. I can remove the table tags using PHP `strip_tags` but i am not sure about deleting the table content. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div>
<p> This is test paragraph</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Desired Output is

```
<div>
<p> This is test paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Thanks @medigeek and all for your answers, i've made few changes to the code so that it works with inline styles.
Solution:

```
$html = '<div>
<p> This is test paragraph</p>
<table style="width:100%"> // Note: Inline Styles
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>';

$regex = '/<table[^>]*>.*?<\/table>/s'; // Regular expression pattern
//This Regex pattern even works with tags that contains inline styles
$replace = '';
$result = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $html);
echo($result);
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @dhinchliff, Hi, Updated the question with desired output

Comment: `strip_tags()` can omit certain tags; keep working at it and post what you tried. Or try a regex pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$teststring = '<div>
<p> This is test paragraph</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>';

$regexpattern = '/<table>.*?<\/table>/s'; // Matching regular expression pattern
$replacement = ''; // Substitute the matched pattern with an empty string
$res = preg_replace($regexpattern, $replacement, $teststring);
echo($res);

?>
```

Matching regular expressions pattern

> `/`=start regex pattern
>
> `<table>` = start matching when you see this text
>
> `.*` = match anything (any characters or empty) in between
>
> `?` = but don't be greedy (as in only match
>   characters between the limits set)
>
> `<\/table>` = stop matching when you see this text
>
> `/` = end regex pattern
>
> `s` = modifier, keep matching even if you stumble upon new line characters

Regular expressions are powerful in matching otherwise seemingly complicated text strings in different programming languages. You may find more information here:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php
- https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works. I've updated regex pattern to work with tags that contains inline styles. Updated the question with solution.

Comment: @syam-s nice job! :-) I also think you might need a question mark `[^>]*?` to avoid the greediness of the `*` asterisk

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with preg_replace:

```
$your_html = '<table......';
$new_html = preg_replace("/(<table>).*?(<\/table>)/s", "", $your_html);
echo $new_html;

/*
OUTPUT:
<div>
 <p> This is test paragraph</p>

</div>
*/
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to do this after the page has already loaded (page loads and certain event triggers the removal) it can't be done with php. Something like this would have to be done using javascript. If you are wanting it to be removed while the page is loading you're going to have to set the output to be within php.

```
<div>
  <p> This is test paragraph</p>
  <?php 
  if(*CASE FOR LOADING*){
     echo "
     <table>
       <tr>
         <th>Firstname</th>
         <th>Lastname</th> 
         <th>Age</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Jill</td>
         <td>Smith</td> 
         <td>50</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     ";
  }
  ?>
</div>
```

Doing it like this will only display the table when the cause is given through PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$content = <<<DATA
<div>
<p> This is test paragraph</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
DATA;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$tables = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table');

while ($tables->length)
{   
    $tables[0]->parentNode->removeChild($tables[0]);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<div> <p> This is test paragraph</p> </div>
```

Comment: It's an interesting approach and works perfectly. Thanks.